# Dynamic routes in Vue-Router work in Development but not Deployment

Tags: webpack, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I've built a small single-page app in Vue using Vue-Cli and Vue-Router, and am using dynamic route matching as mentioned here[1]. Everything works fine during local development, but for some reason the dynamic pages/routes won't load after build (resulting in a 404 error). Other routes (the root page of my project, for example) work fine after build. I'm thinking this may be a webpack config issue.

**Example:**

Root URLS work:

- localhost:8080/arbq/panel   - works
- mydomain.com/arbq/panel/     - works

Dynamic URL works locally but not hosted:

- localhost:8080/arbq/panel/123  - works
- mydomain.com/arbq/panel/123    - 404 Error
  (doesn't load)

**Routes.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Controller from '@/components/Controller'
import Default from '@/components/Default'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/arbq/panel',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/:id',
            name: 'controller',
            component: Controller
        },
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Default
        }
    ]
 })
```

**From Webpack > Config > Index.js**

```
build: {
// Template for index.html
index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

// Paths
assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
assetsPublicPath: '/arbq/panel/',

...
```

Please let me know if you see anything that might be preventing the route from being mapped appropriately, and thanks!

http  [1]: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the vue-router history mode as it's explained on the page, you should check out [HTML5 vue-router's page](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html), you will need to configure your server or maybe change the mode of the `vue-router` to `hash` and this will work because this simulates the history mode by not refreshing the URL, i know it should be a comment but i can't post sorry. Hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks so much Juan - in this case hash mode works for me and it was an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

As of today - January 2024 , the link provided in the answer doesn't work, so in case someone enters and want to know a way to fix this issue if they cannot use the hash mode,can be found in

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode

> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client
> side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a
> 404 error if they access https://example.com/user/id directly in their
> browser. Now that's ugly.
>
> Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple
> catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any
> static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app
> lives in. Beautiful, again!